# Use pm2 with nextjs in docker image

Tags: docker, next.js, pm2

I have a docker image that I am trying to use pm2 on.  For some reason I am getting a 404 error if I run it with the following command in my dockerfile.  Am I calling this correctly?

CMD ["node_modules/.bin/pm2-runtime", "node_modules/.bin/next", "start"]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out.  I added an ecosystem.config.js, added ENV to point to node_modules in my Dockerfile

```
COPY ecosystem.config.js ./
ENV PATH=/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
CMD ["pm2-runtime", "start", "ecosystem.config.js"]
```

ecosystem.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'app-name',
      script: 'yarn start',
    },
  ],
};
```

and it started working